# Create a new list containing references to elements from other lists?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

Assuming I have a class like this:

```
class Base { }
class A : Base { }
class B : Base { }
class C : Base { }
```

And objects like this:

```
A a = new A();
List<B> bs = new List<B>();
List<C> cs = new List<C>();
```

Is it possible to create a new list containing references to the other lists (So that changes are reflected in the original items?
Such as:

```
void modifyContents(List<Base> allItems) {
  //modify them somehow where allItems contains a, bs and cs
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add/remove/replace items in the other lists, but modify the items in the other lists.

```
List<Base> baseList = new List<Base>();
baseList.Add(a);
baseList.AddRange(bs);
baseList.AddRange(cs);
// now you can modify the items in baseList
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Using LINQ [Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) join both lists into the single one `IEnumerable<Base>`
2. Then create a new `List<Base>` instance by passing in constructor previously joined one

**Sample**

```
class Base
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
}

List<B> bs = new List<B>() { new B() };
List<C> cs = new List<C> { new C(), new C() };
var common = new List<Base>(bs.OfType<Base>().Concat(cs.OfType<Base>()));

// bs[0] will be updated
common[0].Id = "1";

// cs[0] will be updated
common[1].Id = "2";

// cs[1] will be updated
common[2].Id = "3";
```